# How to solve the attached sudoku?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

Please explain the logic. I am not trying to solve it using trial and error or using any software. I am just looking for the next step. This sudoku is from apple 'Sudoku King' app.

[image: sudoku]

Comment: I'll repeat what [Bass said before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109432/how-could-i-solve-the-attached-sudoku#comment306588_109432); a Sudoku app which serves up non-unique Sudokus is worse than having no Sudokus at all. **Delete this app, get a better one**.

Comment: I have deleted the app and gone with an that has almost 5 rating after 1.1 M reviews...lets see if it provides unique solutions or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next step is to

> notice that the 5 and 7 can only be in these two squares.
>  [image]

That then allows you to fill in some more numbers.

> [image]

After that, you must choose one of the five possible solutions.

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]